# Blender exporting xml for android

Tags: xml, blender

i'm using blender to draw my 3D objects. I want to export the 3D drwings to xml. I tried to use ORGE Meshes Exporter, but i don't event know how to set it up? Can anyone help me? I'm using windows 7, blender 2.61 and my python version is 3.2.2. How can i set the exporter up? Are there any tutorials? Please..

Answer (score 0):

check out this link
http://www.bayninestudios.com/2011/01/importing-3d-models-in-android/
i also used the latest version of ogre2html 
make sure you set to activate the add on when you install it (put the ogre to xml in the addon directory)

it works but the html code is upside down, i don't know if this is why the android program doesn't like it. Maybe it is a setting in Blender, but it is the first time i use a 3d program and i have problems navigating and finding the controls